# compiler.jar compile list of files simple in one exec

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-compiler

Is it possible to provide a multiple source files each with their own destination file in a single command? That way Java won't have to load up for each file I compile. I am using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.

I know there are better ways than the one at a time,, but they all seem to require code modifications which take too much time for the projects in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can't be done. I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the closure library, you should use the [dependency calculation script](http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/calcdeps.html) to consolidate your code to a single javascript file and then run the closure compiler on it.

If you aren't using the library such that the dependency calculator will work, just do this:

```
cat file1.js file2.js file3.js > alljs.js
java -jar closure-compiler.jar alljs.js
```

Comment: Sorry, the js files in question are required to stay in separate files.

Comment: Are you using the closure library to manage dependencies?  Are you using `goog.provide('myapp.foo');` and `goog.require('myapp.foo');`?